# appcompat v7 21 NavigationDrawerToggle hamburger notShowing Up

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I have drawerActivity and i use this to construct NavigationDrawerTogggle

```
mDrawerToggle = new 
        ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity)this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {};

            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

in my  phone android 4.3 drawer toggle looks like lolipop drawer (hamburger -> arrow animation), in android 4.2.2 it shows only this " < " .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `mDrawerToggle.syncState()`. You can call it right after you initialize your  `mDrawerToggle`